# How do i move the contents of AX register to CS register in 8086 Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, emu8086

The questions that i have seen suggests that i have to use a JMP or a CALL but how.
I want to replace the instruction `MOV CS, AX` with a valid 8086 instruction(instructions) to resolve the error
CS cannot be modified directly (use far JMP or CALL)

Comment: On the 8086, you can just move something to `CS`, but that's generally not what you want.  Changing `CS` changes the segment instructions are loaded from and thus causes a far jump to a location that's hard to predict.  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of examples:

```
        mov     ax,segment_value
        mov     bx,offset_value
        push    ax
        push    bx
        retf

;       ...

        DB      0EAh                ;far jump
        DW      offset_value
        DW      segment_value
```

Comment: You don't *need* to MOV to 2 separate registers, you could reuse AX.  Or use `push immediate` if you don't need to run on original 8086, only 186 and newer. You don't need mov to registers at all, just `push seg` ; `push off` ; `retf`.  The `push` operand can be register, memory, or (on 186 and newer, immediate).

Comment: @PeterCordes - true, in the code I grabbed the first example the mov's were done a few instructions before the retf, and the values were being calculated.